# Xamarin.Forms Plugin.Fingerprint

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, fingerprint, touch-id, android-fingerprint-api

I have been trying to implement the Fingerprint plugin from https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint

The idea is that I want the user to be able to use his fingerprint instead of entering a code when he is signing some work he has done.

It is working for iOS devices but when I try it on Android devices "CrossFingerprint.Current.IsAvailable" always returns false. Does anyone know what could possibly be wrong?

Here is some of the code :

```
    public class FingerprintAuthentication : IFingerprintAuthentication
    {
        public FingerprintAuthentication()
        {
        }

        public bool IsFingerprintIdentificationAvailable()
        {
            return CrossFingerprint.Current.IsAvailable; //this works directly when using an iOS device, but always returns false when using an Android device
        }
    }
```

I have also tried implementing a DependencyService and dealing with the methods in the Android project, but it returns the same results:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(FingerprintAuthentication))]
namespace AVMobile.Droid.NativeImpl
{
    class FingerprintAuthentication : IFingerprintAuthentication
    {
        public async Task<FingerprintAuthenticationResult> AuthenticateFingerprint(string reason)
        {
            var result = await CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync(reason);
            return result;
        }

        public void DisableFingerprintIdentification()
        {
            Core.Settings.Settings.IsUsingFingerprintIdentification = false;
        }

        public void EnableFingerprintIdentification()
        {
            Core.Settings.Settings.IsUsingFingerprintIdentification = true;
        }

        public bool IsFingerprintIdentificationAvailable()
        {
            var result = CrossFingerprint.Current.IsAvailable;
            //return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any clue what could be wrong? As it is working for iOS devices without any DependencyService etc, I can only imagine it has something to do with Android.

Comment: Did you set the right permission? Also are you testing this on an emulator? Did you follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint#android-1)?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using <= 1.2, because `IsAvailable` is not available in the new version.

The reasons for unavailability in your version can be:

1. API doesn't support accessing the fingerprint sensor (Samsung device or Android < 6)
2. Permission for accessing the fingerprint sensor not granted
3. Device has no sensor
4. Fingerprint hasn't been enrolled

I've released a updated version that supports Samsung devices.

It also gives you more information about the reason of the unavailability.

Update the package to 1.3!

**Checking the availability**

```cs
if(await CrossFingerprint.Current.IsAvailableAsync()){
    // ...
}
```

**or**

```cs
var avail = await CrossFingerprint.Current.GetAvailabilityAsync();
// avail contains the availability
```

see: http://smstuebe.de/2016/10/13/fingerprintv1.3/ paragraph Changes -> Breaking for more info.

BTW: you don't need a platform specific implementation. The plugin handles it by itself. You can access `CrossFingerprint.Current` directly in your core code.

BTW2: You may have to update your IDE and NuGet to the very latest version, because I switched to .netstandard already :)

Comment: Very nice plugin. Looking forward to using it very soon. Thank you for all your work on it.